# Kubernetes Find a way to use two selector in one service

Tags: kubernetes, service

I have a load balancer deploying in GKE.
I want to rout 443 port to my Nginx pod, then other UDP port route to my other pod. Just like following figure. Pod 1 is Nginx. Pod 2 is other pod that receive UDP.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZFaI.png)

But I can’t find a way to use two selectors in one service.
Is there a way that satisfy my requirement?
Thank you.

use multi-selector in one service.